# how to fetch json data from cassandra table using cqlsh

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh, nosql

I have a JSON string data in my cassandra table.
While fetching recrods it shows the returned JSON string but i want a particular attribute from this whole json data using cqlsh.
How to fetch using cqlsh or any other way is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such functionality in CQLSH, and unlikely there will be (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6833)

But you can build your own script using https://github.com/datastax/python-driver which will parse your JSON the way you need